# Windows Active Directory Replication

Tags: active-directory, ldap, openldap

To put the problem simply,

I have a piece of code that is currently working on an instance of Windows Active Directory. Now in order to test that I want to use another LDAP server that has the same hierarchy and the same data. I have a local instance of open ldap running. Is there a way where can easily replicate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really if you want to test the content of an Active-Directory, the very best way is to install an Active-Directory Application Mode (ADAM). It's a free product from Microsoft in wich you can easily duplicate you AD Schema an then your datas. ADAM exists under W2K8 under the name of lightweigt Active Directory (LDS).

You can do it whit openldap, but you have to translate the schema and then to export/import your datas usin LDIF.